# composer-rest-server - Not Found: @kyleshockey/js-yaml@^1.0.1

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

While trying to install composer-rest-server, I keep getting error
`npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @kyleshockey/js-yaml@^1.0.1`

I am trying to install latest version of composer-rest-server.

I tried to fix by first manually installing js-yaml
`npm install -g js-yaml`

However, that is not working (as expected).

I tried using custom cache also and got same error 
`npm install --cache /temp/npcache composer-rest-server -g`

I am using node version 8.11.4 and npm version 6.4.0

Please help suggest how to install latest composer-rest-server

Comment: the error suggests you can't contact the NPM registry. Are you behind a proxy / do you have access to the web from your vm? Suggest to try `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` and try installing again, or at the very least try installing a test package to see you can reach the NPM registry.